# if $\log(f(n))=\omega(\log(g(n))$ so then $(f(n))=\omega(g(n)$?

Tags: limits, asymptotics

I want to show that $$f(n)=\omega(g(n)$$ .
for $$f(n)=(\log(n))^n , g(n)=n^{(1/2)\log n}$$
and it is easier for me to show that**
 $$\log(f(n))=\omega(\log(g(n))$$.
is it correct to do that?is it right to claim that
if $\log(f(n))=\omega(\log(g(n))$ so then $(f(n))=\omega(g(n)$?

**

with $$\log(f(n))=n\log(\log n),\log(g(n))=1/2*\log^2n$$
 I show that 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}(\log f(n)/\log(g(n))=\infty $$
and conclude that $(f(n))=\omega(g(n)$

Comment: Use `$\log n$` for $\log n$.

Answer (score 1):

I have corrected your codes here.

> I want to show that $f(n)=\omega(g(n))$ for
>   $$f(n)=\log^n n,g(n)=n^{\frac{1}{2}\log n},$$
>   and it is easier for me to show that
>    $$\log f(n)=\omega(\log g(n)).$$
>   Is it correct to do that ? Is it right to claim that if
>   $$\ \log f(n)=\omega(\log g(n)),$$
>   then
>   $$f(n)=\omega(g(n))\ ?$$
>   With
>   $$\log f(n)=n\log\log n,\log g(n)=\frac{1}{2}\log^2 n,$$
>   I show that 
>   $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\log f(n)}{\log g(n)}=\infty,$$
>   and conclude that $f(n)=\omega(g(n))$.

The answer is presented below.

> **Solution.** For $x\geqslant e$, we have
>   $$e^x\log x\geqslant e^x>\frac{1}{2}x^2,$$
>   Now letting $x=\log n$ can get
>   $$n\log\log n>\frac{1}{2}\log^2 n.$$
>   It shows that for $n\geqslant 16$,
>   $$\log^n n>n^{\frac{1}{2}\log n}.\tag{*}$$
>   We can verify that (*) holds for $n\geqslant 4$. It shows that $f(n)=\omega(g(n))$.$\quad\square$

Comment: Why $e^x >=1+x+1/2x^2$?

Comment: @KIMKES1232 Its derivative is positive.